# Why datetime.tzinfo instance needs a datetime to get its own attributes?

Tags: python, python-datetime

For a long time, I can not understand why a `tzinfo` object needs to be passed a external `datetime` to call its `utcoffset()`, `tzname()` methods, which look pretty much independent to an external time.

For example, I have to manually construct a useless datetime object to get a timezone's name?

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import gettz
tz = gettz("UTC")
tz.tzname(datetime.now()) # UTC
```

Looking at `datetime.py` source code, the implementation of `timezone.tzname()`:

```
def tzname(self, dt):
    if isinstance(dt, datetime) or dt is None:
        if self._name is None:
            return self._name_from_offset(self._offset)
        return self._name
    raise TypeError("tzname() argument must be a datetime instance"
                    " or None")
```

I don't see `dt` is used at all.

Shouldn't a `tzinfo` know its own name, its offset from UTC? In what way a timezone's properties can depend on an external time point? In other words, why is the API designed this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a timezone's offset and name changes at different times of the year, and even historically:

```
>>> tz
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>
>>> tz.tzname(datetime.now())
'CEST'
>>> tz.tzname(datetime(2018, 1, 1))
'CET'
>>> tz.tzname(datetime(1900, 1, 1))
'LMT'
>>> tz.utcoffset(datetime.now())
datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
>>> tz.utcoffset(datetime(2018, 1, 1))
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
```

You don't see this with UTC, but that's rather the exception than the rule.

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that. As a guy live in China where the timezone is so fixed. Thanks for that.

Comment: This is precisely what timezones are for, and why they're more complex than plain offsets.